# angular4 bootstrap multi dropdown not working

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

```
<div [ngClass]="{'dropdown': true, 'open': isDropdownOpen}">
  <button id="dLabel" role="button" (click)="isDropdownOpen = !isDropdownOpen" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-dropdown">
    {{selectedFieldType ? selectedFieldType: item.subType}} <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a tabindex="-1">Text</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width: 200px">
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Number</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a tabindex="-1">Radio Button Group</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>Blank Template</li>
        <!--<li>Gender Selection</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have implemented multi drop down like this previously on Angular2 it worked when i recently migrated it to angular4 it is not working??

And this is the css code i'm using

```
.dropdown{
  display: inline;
}

.dropdown{
  display: inline;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
  border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

the multi dropdown is not appearing on click

plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/KInH93J0av7QdNR1b5ox?p=preview

Comment: can you create a plunker to reproduce

Comment: @Aravind https://plnkr.co/edit/fSvKl27jkkQycuBnzvaJ?p=catalogue

Comment: its not working where is the object value? Create a working plunker

Comment: @Aravind i updated it https://plnkr.co/edit/KInH93J0av7QdNR1b5ox?p=preview